Can two squares intersect in five points? How about in other sets?
I’m trying to prove two squares can intersect in five points. (It was part of a larger problem I was working on where I was trying to determine the possible numbers of points that two squares can intersect each other. More on that below). I know I’m not supposed to use AI to answer questions here. But I was arguing with AI, which said it’s not possible; I have constructed the attached proposal where one square touches the center of the edge of another from its interior, and intersects it in two adjacent sides, as well as the far corners. So I think the answer is “yes.”  But I’m having trouble proving it.

I want to prove it’s possible and need the theoretical coordinates of the corners of each square, and the coordinates of those intersections. This would, I think, solve it.
If you want to help with my original question: in how many other possible numbers of points can two squares intersect? I think the trivial answers are: 1, 2, 4, and 8. Are 3, 7, and more than 8 possible?

I have searched for this question and potential answers and can’t find any reference. I think it has important topological implications. Thank you in advance for your thoughtful and polite help.
Visual proposal:


3 intersections seems to be possible, the case where a square (greater than the base square) is tilted about 12 degrees clockwise and placed such that the bottom right corners coincide, and the bottom edges of two squares form base and hypotenuse of a right triangle.

Can’t picture this but would love a diagram and associated coordinates.

graphing that idea seems to be challenging for me. Here's another case: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p5azlvy6yg
Also, you already have a fabulous answer from Misha.

I guess the answer depends on what somebody thinks "intersect" means. I guess that pretty much everybody would agree that if two lines cross each other, that's an intersection. But if the corner of one square touches the side of another square at exactly one point? Is it one intersection? Is it two intersections? Is it an intersection at all? Seems like that could enter the realm of opinion.

I guess. Perhaps “coincide” or touch might have been better. If a road leads to another to form a “T,” it is, in my world, an intersection. I guess.

Your picture is correct. Here is a graph with two squares, where the size of one is adjustable: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oil2cmvoda
If $r = 2/3$, then they intersect at 5 points. If $2/3 < r < 1$, then they intersect at 7 points. If $0 < r < 2/3$, then they intersect at 3 points.
It should be simple to prove that a line segment can pass through a square at no more than two points (unless it coincides perfectly with one of the edges, of course). Therefore, the four line segments that make up a square cannot intersect another square at more than 8 points.

Another very impressive graphical response. This covers most of the possibilities with the remaining ones being possible if you could somehow rotate that variable square as well. I just didn’t want to mess with the parameters. Thank you that was a very elegant applet.

Here is an animation in which the number of intersections increases from $0$ to $8$ and then back down to $0$, passing through all the integers in between:

If we take the fixed square to be the square with corners at $(\pm1, \pm1)$, then the rotating square has one corner at $(\sqrt2, 0)$ and rotates $360^\circ$ around that point.
Here are the still frames for each number of intersections. If we let $\theta$ be the angle between the positive $x$-axis and the further-counterclockwise side of the square, then the odd numbers occur at specific values of $\theta$, which I've given below.

1 intersection ($\theta = \frac58\pi$)
2 intersections
3 intersections ($\theta = \frac98\pi$)
4 intersections
5 intersections ($\theta \approx 1.152\pi$; more precisely, $\theta = \pi + \tan^{-1}(m)$ where
$7m^4+20m^3-2m^2+12m-9=0$, ugh.)
6 intersections
7 intersections ($\theta = \frac76\pi$)
8 intersections

From a theoretical point of view, the exact values of $\theta$ are not important, because the intermediate value theorem assures us that they must exist, except that we want to be certain that all of the threshold values of $\theta$ are distinct. (Otherwise, we might have accidentally skipped a number of intersections.)
There is only one other number of intersections possible not shown in the animation, and that is $\infty$ - for example, if we place one square exactly on top of the other.

This looks fabulous, I admire how fast you did it. I wish I could slow or pause to follow it.

Been playing with it and appreciate that it may hold a conceptual answer, very thankful!

What would really finish it, is the amount of intersections being shown shortly.

Please could you show the 1, ..., 8-intersection arrangements as separate still images?

Well, you got a bull’s-eye thank you for answering my question so thoroughly!

If you distinguish between intersection points I  and concurrent points C the figure below has 3 concurrent points and 2 regular points of intersection.
Three lines concur at points like C.
No, a situation with 5 regular intersections is not possible.
We can have only $(2,4,8)$ regular intersection points like I.


Not following, as your diagram, like mine, seems to show 5; and regardless, Misha’s beautiful simulation appears to show every solution from 0-8.

as mentioned excluded 3 line intersection concurrent points, included only simple 2 line intersections

Ah, thanks for the clarification. I was counting any intersection.

-1 This 'answer' does not have any foundation or argumentation, let alone a proof. It is just an unsubstantiated claim. Which makes it impossible to know why you claim that six regular intersections are not possible. The answer by Misha clearly shows that it is possible.

@FD_bfa it still claims that 6 "simple"/"regular" intersections are not possible which has been disproven by counterexample
